# ActiveX control Blocks Me.Saved=True

Tags: vba, ms-word, activexobject

Previously I have used this:

```
Private Sub Document_Close()
    Me.Saved = True
End Sub
```

to disable the save prompt when exiting a Word document and changes have been made, however I have added a "Combo Box (ActiveX Control)", and now Word is prompting to save again. Is there a way around this?

I've tried writing code to just delete the Combo Box when the document closes, but the box deletes itself after being used (not my code, it just does), then when the document closes the box doesn't exist and causes an error there. I could just do an if exist/error control, but I feel like that is just getting sloppy instead of finding the root problem... can someone help?

Comment: And what about Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=False?

Comment: @DanielDusek I just tried `Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone` in the `Private Sub Document_Open()`, and separately `ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=False` in the `Private Sub Document_Close()` and neither worked. Am I putting them in the wrong spot?
I have `ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=False` in use when a user clicks a button (after other procedures are performed), but if someone opens the document by accident or doesn't want to use it, closing it with the top right [X] button still brings up the prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If had the same issue, and found the solution with Bing:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-customize/activex-control-blocks-ms-word-vba/71eca664-8e43-4e4f-84c5-59154661ee5a

The following code helped me to get around this issue:

```
Dim WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub App_DocumentBeforeClose(ByVal Doc As Document, Cancel As Boolean)
  'Did the user saved our file?
  If Not ThisDocument.Saved Then
    'Close our file?
    If Doc.Name = ThisDocument.Name Then
      'Cancel the dialog always!
      Cancel = True
      'Set the save state
      ThisDocument.Saved = True
      'Close the document after this event
      Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), Me.CodeName & ".Document_AfterClose"
    End If
  End If
End Sub

Sub Document_AfterClose()
  'Close the document without saving
  ThisDocument.Close False
End Sub

Private Sub cboEquip_Change()
  'Let the document know that a change is made
  ThisDocument.Saved = False
End Sub

Private Sub Document_Open()
  Set App = Application
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, if you look at the user who posted that question... :P  got some views here, but no answers, so I went to the MS forum. Thanks for the response though, very much appreciate your help!

Comment: lol, didn't notice it was your question over at the ms forum.